# AsyncFileUpload fails on the server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am currently using the AsyncFileUpload in my VB.NET web app.

Locally it works perfectly, however on the server it fails to upload a small file (<9k).

I can't even seem to debug this as in JavaScript handlers I have no idea as to how to get the error reason.

```
function uploadError(sender,args) {

            $get("<%=LabelErr.ClientID%>").innerHTML = "Unable to Upload file for the following reason: ", "<span style='color:red;'>" + args.get_errorMessage() + "</span>";

        }
```

The web app can certainly write to the folder I ma trying to save the file as I handle the OnUploadedFileError event and then write a test file to make sure the server can write to the directory (this works)

Does anyone have any ideas or can point in the direction of how I can try and get the error message?

**EDIT:** This is a permissions issue. In the folder the client was trying to upload to permission was denied. Can anyone indicate what user/role should be allowed access to this folder to ensure writeability

Comment: You should add `NETWORK SERVICE`(the account the application pool is running under) in the security tab of the upload-folder and grant write-access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to `grant Read/Write permission to ASPNET user`, have a look on this URL and follow the steps to grant permission
http://www.ironspeed.com/Designer/3.2.4/WebHelp/Part_VI/ASP_NET_User_Does_Not_Have_Permissions_to_Your_Application.htm

http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/denied-access-to-iis-directories